# Using Super User paths for specific topics

Tags: google-search

I want to search Super User and other websites using Google, but I want to limit it to a specific subject (e.g., the R programming language). Using Super User paths for specific topics like:

```
site:http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/r
```

Does not work, as can be seen when comparing [searching using full path](https://www.google.se/search?q=site%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fsuperuser.com%2Fquestions%2Ftagged%2Fr+OR+site%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Funix.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2Ftagged%2Fr++test&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=sb&gfe_rd=cr&ei=SiiQU57xJJGB4ASzkYC4Ag#channel=sb&q=site%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fsuperuser.com%2Fquestions%2Ftagged%2Fr+OR+site%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Funix.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2Ftagged%2Fr++question+&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official) 
compared to [searching entire website with more specific question](https://www.google.se/search?q=site%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fsuperuser.com%2Fquestions%2Ftagged%2Fr+OR+site%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Funix.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2Ftagged%2Fr++test&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a&channel=sb&gfe_rd=cr&ei=SiiQU57xJJGB4ASzkYC4Ag#q=site%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fsuperuser.com+OR+site%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Funix.stackexchange.com++question+%22r%22+%22programming+language%22+%22tag%22&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official). Also note the first hit being one step in the direction I want, but since this path itself does not hold the questions in its path it does not solve my issue.

There should, however, be a better way to do this, by having a very specific Google search tag for the R programming language, which would have to be either in the path, on the webpage, or tagged differently. Seeing as Super User has a good tag system, I am optimistic that this can be used to solve my question.

Is there a solution to this that always works on Super User and similar sites?

Comment: Are you asking if Google can search in the manner you describe?

Comment: I know that Google can not search like that directly, due to the linking of tags to their topics not being structured like that. I also know that "link:http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/r" does not work due to other constraints in how Google does their querries. So in a sense I want a workaround that fixes this limitation